# ANR rate too high - "Input dispatching timed out" errors?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm now running my android app which is query based lot of sql queries are return for report perpose - works well so far, crashes are fine, but I'm getting quite a lot of ANR errors - mostly the "Input dispatching timed out. Runner Activity (server) is not responding." ones. mostly on android 12 and 13 version

This is the latest one - "Input dispatching timed out (1f9d15 com.brusgames.kingofcrusaderstrongholds/com.brusgames.kingofcrusaderstrongholds.RunnerActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5002ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false))" - others have different "Waited..." notes such as "Waited 10000ms for MotionEvent", so it's not always the same one.

My guess is that there is lot of sql query executing too much happening at the same time, or too much stuff queued - is there a way how to extract more specifics from the crash report? I haven't found any  I'm struggling to find out from the logs what actually went wrong, or at least which component caused the crash...

Comment: Are you *really* using SQL Server 2000? That completely ran out of support around a **decade** ago. Android didn't even exist when that version was released.

Comment: I dunno android, but you shouldn't run SQL queries and other potentially slow running tasks in the UI thread